# Inconsistent behaviour in Ribbon Toolbar and Mouse Context Menu

Tags: 2013, cme

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, and I observe an inconsistent behaviour in the Ribbon Toolbar and the Mouse Context Menu. For example: If I select a publication and want to see the "Blueprinting Hierarchy"; the corresponding button in the Ribbon Toolbar comes as disabled but if I right click on the same publication then I can see the option for "Blueprinting Hierarchy" as enabled and by clicking on it I can see the entire Blueprint hierarchy without any issue. See the screen shot below:

[image]

[image]

Few more points:

- I am logged in as a System Admin user in the CM
- This is happening on two entirely different installation - One on Physical Server and another one on Cloud instance

**Question:** Is it a bug and everybody is experiencing it or is it something I am missing at my end?

Comment: i also see similar behavior in my environment.

Comment: Interesting!! It seems a bug, as if you select the Building Block folder with in the publication, it still shows Disabled in the Ribbon; however, if you right click on the folder and wait for few seconds, the option in Ribbon Toolbar got enable

Comment: I cannot reproduce that part; the toolbar button becomes enabled immediately and it doesn't matter if I right-click or not.

Comment: not sure if you have followed up these exact steps - 1) I select and explore a publication in the Tree View in left pane 2) In the publication, I select the Building Block folder in the Tree View 3) Notice that the Blueprint Hierarchy button is disabled on the Ribbon Toolbar 4) Right click on the Building Block folder in the Tree View and wait for couple of seconds 5) The Blueprint Hierarchy button got enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually by design. The buttons in the toolbar will only apply to the selection in the list -- never the selection in the tree.

This was a bit more intuitive back when the toolbar only spanned the top of the list, but the functionality remains the same.

The context menu options, however, will apply to the selection in either the tree or the list, depending on where you clicked.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this clarifies the design and the behaviour :)